# Jenkins-X version 3 command to install helm chart

Tags: jenkins-x, jenkins-x-3

Can someone help me with the jx command to install an application's helm chart ??
I do know that this can be acheived in jx 2.x versions using

```
jx step helm
```

But in jx v3.x, i do see that this command in no longer available.
So, if i were to install an application's helm chart using jx v3.x, how can i do that ??

Thanks in advance.